# Block elements get bigger and don't stay centered vertically when resizing the browser window

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a responsive website with a sidebar navigation menu. Everything has been working smoothly until I started to build and design the navigation menu. It looks like I want it to in a full-sized browser window but when resized to make it smaller, the block elements start to get bigger in comparison to the rest of the page and the text doesn't stay centered. I may be making a stupid mistake, as I am quite new to CSS.

I want the navigation bar to be the same height as the part of the page that is containing the text, so I enclosed everything in a `<div>` with the background color green, then floated the div containing the text with a white background to the right and the div containing the navigation links to the left. This is in example of the HTML and CSS code for the navigation links:

```
<div id="navigation">   
    <ul>        
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

```css
#navigation {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-top: 2vw;
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
}

#navigation a {
    font-size: 1.2vw;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 2vw;
    padding-top: 0.5vw;
    padding-bottom: 0.5vw;
    padding-right: 0.5vw;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I want the block elements to resize with the rest of the page and the links inside them to be vertically centered. Am I doing something wrong?

[Here's a comparison between the view in a normal sized window and the view in a smaller one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynUbi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved in several ways, but the cleanest would probably be using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) or [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) layout in CSS.

Something like this? (using flexbox):

```css
.layout {
  /* Use flex layout */
  display: flex;
  /* make the layout use the full viewport height */
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.main {
  /* Make the main element grow */
  flex: 1;
  padding: 1em;
}

.nav {
  /* Center children vertically */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* Keep the nav width at 15% */
  flex-basis: 15%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 1em;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

.nav .menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul class="menu">        
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main class="main">
    Content ...
  </main>
</div>
```